# Electrically non-conductive molten salts

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electrochemistry, chemical-compounds

I'm researching an idea for molten salt as a coolant. The information that I lack is the conductivity of molten salts.  The basic question is "what are the best insulating molten salts?"  Comparisons or suggestions are also welcome.

Assume salts are in the liquid phase, temperatures are between 100 C and 800 C, the pressure is about 1 atm. Eutectics or solutions are also relevant.

Answer (score 1):

An *insulating molten salt* is by definition an oxymoron.

Salts are made up of ionic lattices, for example in the case of table salt, aka sodium chloride, a lattice of equal numbers of sodium cations ($\mathrm{Na^+}$) and chloride anions ($\mathrm{Cl^-}$). Although ions are charge carriers (just like electrons), in a solid salt these ions have no mobility and without mobile charge carriers the solid salt doesn't electricity.

But molten salts aren't made of lattices and the ions are free to move: molten salts thus *always* conduct electricity.

No doubt some have higher conductivity than others but well above their melting points they all conduct rather well.

Comment: Yes, I see this point.  My point is that I need numbers behind how well or poorly these conductors conduct.  For instance, solid metals make great conductors, but silver (1.59x10-8 Ohm meter) is far superior to lead (2.05x10-7 Ohm meter) [link](https://www.thebalance.com/electrical-conductivity-in-metals-2340117).

Comment: Apart from a few datapoints on selected salts, only some specialist journals might list some values, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are none. At least, I cannot imagine classifying a liquid without ionic conductivity as a molten salt.

Edit: But have you considered molten sulfur?